# Sine function - getting coordinates from the graph.

Tags: functions, trigonometry

I have trouble with getting coordinates from the sine graph:

[image]

The format of the function is:
$f(x)=\sin(x-k)+c$

I need to find the coordinates of `A`. Could you give me just a little hint where to start from? I understand that the period of the function is $2\pi$, and that the horizontal coordinate is $\frac{2x}{3}$, but I have no idea how to get the vertical coordinate which, according to the exercise, is $\frac{3}{2}$, all I can say is that it should be equal to $c+1$ as the maximum point is one because there is no vertical stretch, and the graph is translated up by $c$.

[image]

I am expected to solve the problem in this order.

Comment: You need $c$ to write down the coordinates of $A$. As the question does not say that you have to give the numerical values, a valid answer could be $A(\frac{2\pi}{3}, 1+c)$

Comment: @trancelocation Uhm, thats what I wrote, but they stated that the answer is 3/2. I came to a conclusion that this problem is not solvable with what they have taught us before, so thanks for all the help.

Answer (score 1):

We have $0=f(2 \pi)$ and $0=f(\frac{4 \pi}{3})$. This gives two equations for $k$ and $c$.

Solve this system of equations. Then look for $x_0 \in (0, \frac{4 \pi}{3}) $ such that $f'(x_0)=0$.

Then we have $A=f(x_0)$.

Comment: Uhmm, I need to find $k$ and $c$ in next part, so I guess I cannot use this... What is $f'()$? A derivative? We haven't studied these yet...

Answer (score 1):

You have $$f(x)=\sin(x-k)+c$$ Using the two points
$$f\left(\frac{4 \pi }{3}\right)=\sin\left(\frac{4 \pi }{3}-k\right)+c= 0\tag 1$$
$$f(2\pi)=\sin(2\pi-k)+c=-\sin(k)+c=0\tag 2$$

Subract $(2)$ from $(1)$ to get a simple trigonometric equation in $k$, namely
$$\sin\left(\frac{4 \pi }{3}-k\right)+\sin(k)=0 $$ Use $\sin(p)+\sin(q)=??$, then solve it for $k$, and back to $(1)$ or $(2)$ get $c$ .

On the other hand, point $A$ seems to be a maximum. Since $$f'(x)=\cos(x-k)$$ at this point $f'(x)=0$. Then $x= ?$; at this point compute $f(x)$ and you are done.

Comment: Umm, is $f'()$ is a derivative? As we did not study these. Also, its not $\frac{4\pi}{3}$ but $\frac{4x}{3}$ in the picture. Also, I cannot get c and k before writing the coordinates of A, is it really possible to do it in this order(first getting coordinates of A, then getting k and c)?

Comment: I edited my question and added the full problem.

Comment: @Danielius. As far as I can "see" it (I am almost blind), it is $\frac{4\pi}{3}$

Comment: OOPS, my bad. That makes a lot more sense.

Answer (score 1):

I would start by figuring out $k$ and $c$. From the graph, you can see that
$f(0)= \sin{-k} +c = - \sin{k} + c = 0 \Rightarrow c = \sin{k}$

and also

$
f\left(\frac{4\pi}{3} \right) = \sin{\left(\frac{4\pi}{3} - k \right)} + c = 0
$

Now we can use $\sin{(x-y)} = \sin{x} \cos{y}  - \cos{x}\sin{y} $
$$
\Rightarrow \sin{\left(\frac{4\pi}{3} - k \right)} = \sin{\frac{4\pi}{3}} \cos{k}  - \cos{\frac{4\pi}{3}}\sin{k} = -\frac{\sqrt{3}}{2} \cos{k}  + \frac{1}{2}\sin{k} 
$$
and therefore 
$$
f\left(\frac{4\pi}{3} \right) = -\frac{\sqrt{3}}{2} \cos{k}  + \frac{1}{2}\sin{k}  + c = 0
$$
We can also use $\cos{k} = \sqrt{1- \sin^2{k}} = \sqrt{1-c^2}$, giving an equation for $c$:
$$
-\frac{\sqrt{3}}{2} \sqrt{1-c^2}  + \frac{1}{2}c  + c = 0
$$
Can you continue from here?

Comment: Yes I could have solved the problem like that, but the thing is that I first need to find the coordinates of $A$ and only then I need to find $k$ and $c$. Moreover, even though I know that $\sin(x−y)=\sin(x)\cos(y)−\cos(x)\sin(y)$, this formula was not shown in the textbook yet :D So is there any way to solve this without using this formula and in correct order? Otherwise, this exercise is unsolvable using the ideas currently presented in the textbook.

Comment: And, it is not $\frac{4\pi}{3}$ but $\frac{4x}{3}$ in the picture.

Answer (score 1):

- Symmetry gives the first negative minimum of $f(x)$ in the middle between $\frac{4\pi}{3}$ and $2\pi$ at $x_m = \frac{2\pi + \frac{4\pi}{3}}{2}= \frac{5}{3}\pi$. Since $\sin(\frac{3}{2}\pi)= -1$ we get the shift
  $$\frac{5}{3}\pi- k = \frac{3}{2}\pi \Rightarrow \boxed{k = \frac{\pi}{6}}$$
- $f(2\pi) = \sin(2\pi - \frac{\pi}{6}) + c = 0$ 
  $$\Rightarrow \boxed{c = \sin \frac{\pi}{6} = \frac{1}{2} }$$